# Can't retrieve values between attributes, Scraping

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm trying to retrieve a value from a site yet I get no value between the attributes.(except for id=Avg Played). I've tried using both Scrapy and Beautiful Soup to no avail!
Here's my BeautifulSoup/Urllib2 code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


site = "http://www.lolking.net/champions/singed?#/overview"
request= urllib2.Request(site, headers={'User-Agent':'Chrome/44.0.2403.107'})
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
html = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

champ_stats = soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class" : "champ-stats"})

champ_stats2 = soup.findAll('strong', attrs={"class" : "champ-stats"})


for x in champ_stats:
    print x.text, x

print '\n now showing more specifically: \n'    
for x in champ_stats2:
    print x.text, x
```

I've also made a scraper using Scrapy(got the same results):

```
import scrapy


class StatsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "stat_spider"
    start_urls = ["http://www.lolking.net/champions/singed?#/overview"]
    def parse(self, response):
        selector = '.champ-stats'
        for stats in response.css(selector):    
            stat_selector = 'strong ::text'
            name_selector = 'span ::text'
            yield {
                'stat': stats.css(stat_selector).extract_first(),
                'name' : stats.css(name_selector).extract_first()
            }
```

This is what the html looks like in the browser(what I want to retrieve):

```
html = """            <div class="champ-stats">
                <strong id="winrate">48.3</strong><small>%</small>
                <span>Win Rate</span>
            </div>
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <div class="champ-stats">
                <strong id="popularity">0.8</strong><small>%</small>
                <span>Popularity</span>
            </div>
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <div class="champ-stats">
                <strong id="banrate">0.5</strong><small>%</small>
                <span>Ban Rate</span>
            </div>
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <div class="champ-stats">
                <strong>10.2</strong>
                <span>Avg Played</span>
            </div>
        </div> """
```

I'm guessing the site has a method for preventing people from scraping this data? If so, is there a way around that?

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off using the requests module, rather than urllib2; it's just simpler to use. I should mention though that BeautifulSoup might not be enough to fully scrape this page depending on what you want from it. You might need to resort to selenium or scrapy.

```
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('http://www.lolking.net/champions/singed?#/overview').content
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> champ_stats = soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class" : "champ-stats"})
>>> for x in champ_stats:
...     x.text, x
...     
('\n%\nWin Rate\n', <div class="champ-stats">
<strong id="winrate"></strong><small>%</small>
<span>Win Rate</span>
</div>)
('\n%\nPopularity\n', <div class="champ-stats">
<strong id="popularity"></strong><small>%</small>
<span>Popularity</span>
</div>)
('\n%\nBan Rate\n', <div class="champ-stats">
<strong id="banrate"></strong><small>%</small>
<span>Ban Rate</span>
</div>)
('\n10.2\nAvg Played\n', <div class="champ-stats">
<strong>10.2</strong>
<span>Avg Played</span>
</div>)
```

Edit:

I'm not sure this is entirely apposite. If I understand you correctly, those values can be scraped using selenium.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get('http://www.lolking.net/champions/singed?#/overview')
>>> for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="champ-stats"]/strong'):
...     item.text
...     
'48.4'
'0.8'
'0.4'
'10.2'
```

Comment: Hi Bill, I resorted to Scrapy yet had no success. The problem is that I'm not getting any values between the strong attributes with id's 'winrate', 'banrate' and 'popularity'.

Comment: Hi Finn: Please see edit. If you need to use Scrapy then do comment.

Comment: Thanks for that! I gave it a go. However I intended this to be used in a mock website. Guessing the use of selenium is too slow for showing that data on a website?

Comment: You're welcome. What you probably need is: the combination of scrapy, splash and scrapy-splash. splash is a lightweight browser that 'does' all the Javascript in a page and gives back the DOM. scrapy-splash is middleware. Guess why I didn't offer to discuss that in one answer. ;)